# Card flip on click instead of hover

Tags: html, css

I have this

```
.front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
}

.back {
    background: rgb(176, 190, 197, 0.8);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
}


.back-content {
    color: #2c3e50;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.card:hover > .front {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg);
    
}

.card:hover > .back {
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
```

the hover works fine on my computer but I realized you cannot hover on mobile. when I change it to :active instead it makes me hold it to keep the back part of the card displayed. Is there a way to make it so I just have to click it for it to rotate and click again for it to rotate back to the front? I cannot seem to find a solution and it’s really frustrating as I don’t have much time left to complete this (it’s a gift)

Comment: You need to use a javascript click handler to add or remove a class. If you add the class 'front' it will show the front side. If you add the class 'back' it will play the animation to the back side

Comment: Okay, would I use an eventlistener or a function?

Comment: @ftfrenchtoast what about this?: https://jsfiddle.net/james2doyle/qsQun/

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: Here is the full code https://jsfiddle.net/ftfrenchtoast/2owksrLf/

Comment: Please make a snippet of your code and then explain based on that

Comment: I posted the entire thing

Comment: Also post the .html code please

Comment: It’s all there https://jsfiddle.net/ftfrenchtoast/2owksrLf/